# How exactly does Kubernetes work?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

I understand how containers work and the concept of containerizing.

However, I am having trouble understanding how Container Cluster Managers work. I was reading through this [excellent blog post](https://medium.com/spire-labs/mitigating-an-aws-instance-failure-with-the-magic-of-kubernetes-128a44d44c14#.1naze4qfc), which blew my mind about Kubernetes.

**So, I wanted to know how exactly do these systems like Kubernetes, Docker, etc work?** I tried reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes), but I wanted a much more basic-level explanation.

**Are these similar to how Zoo-Keeper work? (like the Master-Worker architecture)?**

Comment: If you are interested in learning about Kubernetes architecture, here are the design docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/v1.5.1/docs/design If you have specific questions after your read the docs, please feel free to ask in their forums. If there is something specific you feel should be asked here, I would suggest to at least used the terminology from those docs.

Comment: you may want to try asking this at the K8s slack channel as well.